# Mysql multiple limit with random record

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

i have created a query to display my packages.

it is working fine but my issue is to get random product for each meta_value.

And for that i need to set the limit in it.

Suppose if meta_value='0' there is 10 products but i want to display two random record from it.

If meta_value='2' i want to display 5 random record from it.

Like this i want to get from the sql.

My query is,

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT * 
FROM wp_posts qp 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wpm ON (qp.ID = wpm.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 AND (((qp.post_title LIKE '% %') OR (qp.post_content LIKE '% %'))) AND 
      qp.post_type = 'listing_type' AND qp.post_status IN ('publish', 'private') AND 
      wpm.meta_key = 'packageID' AND wpm.meta_value IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4')
GROUP BY qp.ID 
ORDER BY wpm.meta_value  ASC, qp.post_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5934739/212692,
you can combine prepared statement with random number generation in order to get random limit in your query.

```
SET @a = (SELECT FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 9));

PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM user LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @a;
```

in FLOOR, you can replace 1 and 9 with the range you want for your dynamic limit.

Though, you may also need to use UNION in order to get different LIMIT-ed records with different meta_value values.