# How to use a dynamic limit in sql query

Tags: mysql

I have a query `SELECT * FROM grades WHERE userid = 4123;`

I want to limit this query

I have a query `SELECT * FROM grades WHERE userid = 4123 LIMIT(2);`

This works great but if I want this limit to be dynamic from another query.

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM count_table WHERE course = 131;`

doing this gives me a syntax error

`SELECT * FROM grades WHERE userid = 4123 LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM count_table WHERE course = 131);`

**if this is not possible at all, then is there an alternative way to achieve this?**

please help.!

Comment: 'LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, ' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html. Try dynamic sql.

Comment: thanks, is there any alternate way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a SQL query with dynamic LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934315/how-to-write-a-sql-query-with-dynamic-limit)

Comment: What version of MySQL? It may be possible in MySQL 8.x.

Comment: By the way, using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in MySQL 8.x using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Assuming you order the rows by some column (I guessed the column `ID`... change it as needed), you can do:

```
select
  g.*
from (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over(order by id) as rn -- change ordering as needed
  from grades
  ) g
join (
  SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM count_table WHERE course = 131
) c on g.rn <= c.cnt
```

Comment: ```sql
<e>Query: select g.* from ( select *, row_number() over(order by id) as rn from grades ) g join ( SELECT COUNT(id) as cn...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by id) as rn 
  from grades
  ) g
join (
  SELECT C' at line 6
```

Comment: Check you MySQL version. It seems you don't have 8.x yet.